# Quartz scheduler during server restart

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing

I am trying to implement a quartz scheduler which should run every n days.

Say I wrote a trigger which runs every 10 days. If I restart my server on 9th day, the cron jobs will be reloaded based on current time. So it won't fire on the 10th day instead it will fire on 19th day.

Is there any way we to trigger jobs based on last run date so that it will trigger on 10th day.

Comment: simple idea : save quartz state thread peer day .

Comment: Did you try to look at Job Persistence? http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features.html

Answer (score 0):

If you "just" have to remember your job executions, you have to persist it in some way. An approach with minimum impact would be using something like a [Quartz JDBCJobStore](https://vageeshhoskere.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/jdbc-job-store-quartz-scheduler/).

Maybe you are already using Spring and in case you need a more "sophisticated" (single steps, start & stop & restart) way take a look at [Spring Batch](https://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/).